# How to update/Change the date format to MM/dd/yyyy from dd/MM/yyyy format in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, date-formatting

In my db DOB is saved in dd/mm/yyyy format. i want to change the DOB date format to MM/dd/yyyy. How can i do that?

Comment: What datatype do you have? `DateTime`, or is it really a `varchar` with this format?

Comment: What is the type of the field in the database? It should be `DATE`, which means it isn't stored in any text format at all. You should differentiate between when you need text, and when you need the real value. Ideally, you should only use text representations when you absolutely need them, e.g. when you're displaying them to a client.

Comment: Is this `dd/mm/yyyy` typo becuase `mm` is minutes ?

Comment: Do not convert anything! Date is a date no matter of its form.

Comment: Take a look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: @Mureinik data type of DOB is nvarchar

Comment: @Deepak check my upated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First i want to know which datatype you are using for saving your date value. There is nothing provided with your code no sample code, table details nothing. anyway 
i think your 'date of birth' field datatype is datetime,then you can use the following example

```
create table checktable(
    ID          int,
    name        nvarchar (30),
    dob  datetime);
```

> Example data insert into the table

```
insert into checktable(ID,name,dob) values(10,'myname','03/01/2014');
```

//..........

```
    select * from checktable
```

> //Use CONVERT() it will give you the desired output

```
    SELECT TOP 1 ID, dob,CONVERT(varchar,dob,101) 'mm/dd/yyyy' 

 FROM checktable
```

**UPDATE**

if your datatype is varchar and now it is in the format mm/dd/yyyy and you want to change it into dd/mm/yyyy format then use the following example it will help you

```
create table checktable1(
    ID          int,
    name        nvarchar (30),
    dob  varchar(20));
```

> // insert sample data

```
 insert into checktable1(ID,name,dob) values(10,'myname','21/05/2010');
    select * from checktable1
```

> // change the format using substring()

```
  select * FROM checktable1
    select dob,substring(dob,4,3)+substring(dob, 1, 3)+substring(dob, 7, 4) from checktable1
```

> It will give you result in 05/21/2010 (mm/dd/yyyy)format

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft SQL: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Syntax for CONVERT:

```
CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )
```

use example:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) AS [MM/DD/YYYY]
```

For other databases search **Date and Time Functions** in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The CONVERT() function is a general function that converts an expression of one data type to another.

The CONVERT() function can be used to display date/time data in different formats.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Answer (score 0):

if your data  type is `DateTime` then no need to convert it, in later you can convert its format as you want but if your are using `varchar` or `nvarchar`
then you can use `CONVERT()` as below

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '23/10/2016', 103)
```

> Result : 2016-10-23 00:00:00.000

if just want to conver in date then

```
SELECT convert(date, '23/10/2016', 103)
```

> Result : 2016-10-23

for more information and other formats

http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/

and if you just want to convert string to sting then

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar,'23/10/2016',101)
```

> Result : 23/10/2016

Answer (score 0):

This is the query to show all data in dd/mm/yyyy format.Type your column name that contains date in place of datecolumnname and your table name in place of tablename in below  query:

```
 select convert(varchar,datecolumname,103) as datecolumname from tablename
```